# With which Framework to Detect Augmented Reality Markers in Single Image

Tags: augmented-reality, marker, artoolkit

I need to detect augmented reality markers in single images (or at least in a video saved on disk, not live captured) on OS X in C/C++, python or MATLAB.

I tried ARToolKit, but it looks like reading videos from disk only works on windows:

```
vid = arVideoOpen( "inputDevice=AVI_FILE,fileName=/Users/jw/Desktop/matlabvideo/example.avi" );
```

The framework should be specialized on ARMarker detection (for higher accuracy of the edge points), not just a simple pattern detection, e.g. with openCV.

Does anyone know about alternatives to ARToolKit or how to read videos on OS X with ARToolKit? I already did a deep search without finding any working alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after some more search I found [Aruco](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26).
Works on OS X with single images. The drawback is it does only work with certain markers...